# Drawing the fundamental domain with TeX

Tags: domain, drawing

I am new to using TeX as a tool to draw something, I am just familiar with typing formulas etc.

How can I draw the fundamental domain of the action of the special linear group acting on the upper half plane?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: A general advice would be to look around on this site for similar diagrams and change the code according to your needs. It is always better to ask more specific questions which are more likely to help others. Also, once you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you tried so far, it is more likely that others will help you as it becomes clearer what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

- The basic TikZ command for this type of diagram is `\draw`.
- Straight lines require just the coordinates `(a,b)--(c,d)`. Default unit is 1cm. Rectangular `(x,y)` or polar `(θ:r)` coordinates can be used. Circular arcs are drawn using the `arc(θ₁:θ₂:radius)` option.
- Line thickness can be selected from a variety of options such as `thin` (the default), `thick`, `very thick`, etc., or be set to any width you choose.
- Line styles include `dashed`, `dotted` and many others.
- Text elements (including math using $..$) can be added using `node[options]{text}`
- The `fill` option will fill the drawn region with the selected color.
- The `\path` command is just like `\draw` except the path is invisible.
- There are many, many more options but this should get you started.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw[densely dashed] (1,0) arc (0:60:1) (-1,0) arc (180:120:1);
\draw[very thick, fill=gray!30] (.5,1.5) --node[right, pos=.9]{$e^{2\pi i/6}=\rho$} (60:1) arc (60:120:1)
    --node[left, pos=.1]{$\rho^2=e^{2\pi i/3}$} (-.5,1.5);
\draw[-latex] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0)node[below]{Re};
\draw[-latex] (0,-.2) -- (0,1.7)node[right]{Im};
\path(-1,0) --node[below, pos=0]{$-1$}node[below right, pos=.5]{0}node[below, pos=1]{1} (1,0)
    (0,1)node[below right]{$i$};
\draw(-.5,.02)--(-.5,-.02)node[below]{$-\frac{1}{2}$}(.5,.02)--(.5,-.02)node[below]{$\frac{1}{2}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```